# Looping through a list of tuples to make a POST request with each tuple

Tags: python, list, post, google-analytics, tuples

I have a list of tuples here:

```
import datetime
import requests
from operator import itemgetter

original = [(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 50), u'78:E4:00:0C:50:DF', u' 8', u'Hon Hai Precision In', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 50), u'78:E4:00:0C:50:DF', u' 8', u'Hon Hai Precision In', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 48), u'9C:2A:70:69:81:42', u' 5', u'Hon Hai Precision In 12:', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'00:1E:4C:03:C0:66', u' 9', u'Hon Hai Precision In', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'20:C9:D0:C6:8F:15', u' 8', u'Apple', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'68:5D:43:90:C8:0B', u' 11', u'Intel Orate', u' MADEGOODS'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'68:96:7B:C1:76:90', u' 15', u'Apple', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'68:96:7B:C1:76:90', u' 15', u'Apple', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'04:F7:E4:A0:E1:F8', u' 32', u'Apple', u''), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'04:F7:E4:A0:E1:F8', u' 32', u'Apple', u'')]

data = [x[:-2] for x in original]

newData = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(0))

print newData

[(datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'00:1E:4C:03:C0:66', u' 9'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'20:C9:D0:C6:8F:15', u' 8'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'68:5D:43:90:C8:0B', u' 11'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'68:96:7B:C1:76:90', u' 15'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'68:96:7B:C1:76:90', u' 15'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'04:F7:E4:A0:E1:F8', u' 32'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 47), u'04:F7:E4:A0:E1:F8', u' 32'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 48), u'9C:2A:70:69:81:42', u' 5'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 50), u'78:E4:00:0C:50:DF', u' 8'), (datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 12, 19, 24, 50), u'78:E4:00:0C:50:DF', u' 8')]
```

The first element in each tuple is a date/time, the second is a MAC address and the third is a RSSI strength.

I am looking for the best way to send each tuple in a POST request the Google's Measurement Protocol, like so:

```
requests.post("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect", 
              data="v=1&tid=UA-22560594-2&cid="varMACADDRESS"&t=event&ec="varDATETIME"&ea="varRSSI")
```

The "varXXXXXX"s represent the elements of the tuples.

This is what I think should be the solution, but I can't think of how to assign the elements of each tuple to the %s's:

```
for tuples [:10] in newData:
    requests.post("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect", 
              data="v=1&tid=UA-22560594-2&cid="%s"&t=event&ec="%s"&ea="%s")
```

What would be the most efficient and pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the tuple values as you iterate over the list and use [format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to insert the values.

```
for date, mac, rssi in newData:
    requests.post("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect", 
          data="v=1&tid=UA-22560594-2&cid={}&t=event&ec={}&ea={}".format(
              mac, 
              date, 
              rssi)
    )
```

Comment: this works great, would you mind explaining how python knows that date mac and rssi are the 3 elements of each tuple?

Comment: Python doesn't know that. That's just the name YOU yourself are choosing to give them and Python does positional unpacking for each of the elements in the tuple for the particular tuple you are on for that iteration and gives them the names provided.
You could also write the same for loop like,
`for tup in newData:` and then instead of `mac, date, rssi` as the arguments to `format`, you would give it `tup[1], tup[0], tup[2]`.

Comment: If you were to add an extra name, say like so, `for date, mac, rssi, something in newData:`, Python would complain that there weren't enough elements to unpack.

Answer (score 2):

Just take advantage of the fact that you can specify a `dict` to the `data` kwarg and requests will [handle the form-encoding for you](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

```
for date,mac,rssi in some_collection_of_tuples:
    payload = {'t':'event','v':'1','ec':date,'cid':mac,...} #etc
    requests.post("http://www.google-analytics.com/collect", data=payload)
```